# Parsing PDF document using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, extract

How to extract contents of .pdf file for further manipulation using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a PDF library in order to grab and write stuff for PDFs.  An informative post about extracting contents from a PDF: http://community.livejournal.com/php/295413.html